# Can susano protect users from all genjutsus?

Tags: anime, naruto

As we see in final battle with madara, sasuke's susano was able to protect them from being captured in infinite tsukuyomi. Does this happen if susano's user has rinnegan or this will happen with susano just being activated while genjutsu is cast?

Comment: Please move it to anime stack exchange if its more suitable, I was not sure where to post.

Comment: Kabuto genjutsu via tayuya affect both itachi and sasuke susanoo